# How to troubleshoot lost 6to4 packets?

Tags: linux, ipv6, 6to4

On my VDS, both 6to4 and Teredo seem to work poorly (packet loss is about 40%).

[just-ping.com](http://just-ping.com/) shows packet loss 10%-80% both for 6to4 and for Teredo address, but 0% for IPv4 address.

When running `ping6 -n ipv6.google.com` and `tcpdump -n 'host 192.88.99.1'` I see more `ICMP6, echo request` packets going to 192.88.99.1  than `ICMP6, echo reply` coming back from 192.88.99.1.

How to debug it? Is 6to4 unreliability probably caused by misconfiguration on my side or problems on some remote side?

Comment: Meanwhile have just configured the HE tunnel and see no lost packets there.

Comment: 6to4 is just naturally unreliable. Get a tunnel, or better yet a VPS provider with native IPv6. They are starting to show up in greater quantities now.

Comment: I have never yet seen any native IPv6 on any hosts I've logged into. (actually I rarely see non-NAT-ted IPv4 as well).

Comment: http://www.lowendbox.com/?s=ipv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging 6to4 problems is almost impossible. Your outgoing 6to4 traffic (to non-6to4 destinations) will go to the IPv4 address 192.88.99.1. There are multiple public 6to4 relays on the internet for that address. You would need to do a traceroute to 192.88.99.1 to find out which one you are currently (it changes over time) using. That is one bit of information. Then it depends which IPv6 destination you are connecting to. They will use the closest 6to4 relay for *them*. It is almost impossible to find out which relay they are using.

Either of those relays might be causing packet loss.